# WordPress post number not working in pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show 50 posts. 10 posts per page. I want serial post number like 1, 2, 3...50 before the title. By using the code, I get number in 1st page 1-10 but the 2nd page also shows same 1-10. But I want 2nd page will be started from 11.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => $paged
) );
?>

<?php $counter=0;?>
<?php while( $post_query->have_posts() ) : $post_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="single_post">
        <h2><?php echo $counter;  ?> <?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>

    <?php $counter++; ?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<!--Pagination-->
<div class="pagination text-center">
    <?php
    echo paginate_links(array(
        'total' => $post_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $paged,
        'prev_text' => __('Previous Page', 'text_domain'),
        'next_text' => __('Next Page', 'text_domain')
    ));
    ?>
</div>
<!--Pagination end-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a counter based on the page just change the `$counter` declaration from

```php
$counter=0;
```

to

```php
$counter = ($paged-1) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `wp_reset_query()` and then add it after the pagination.

Comment: I think PHPNoob means, remove the `wp_reset_query()` and then add it after the pagination.

Comment: …also, it should be `wp_reset_postdata()` not `wp_reset_query()` ?